# MS-Access : Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error

I keep getting a syntax error (missing operator) in query expression for this formula in `MS-Access`.

```
IIf([Employee List].[Employee Type]=”Employee”,Format([Employee List].[Date of Birth],'dd/mm/yyyy'),’01/01/1910’) AS Date of Birth
```

Basically for employee type `employee` show their date of birth in the employee list otherwise show `01/01/1910` for everyone else.

Does anyone know why and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your quotes are wrong.  MS Access uses double quotes for strings:

```
IIf([Employee List].[Employee Type] = "Employee",
    Format([Employee List].[Date of Birth], "dd/mm/yyyy"),
    "01/01/1910"
   ) AS DateofBirth
```

Also, the column alias needs to be a single word or be escaped.

Comment: @Analyst1 . . . If this is your preferred answer, you can accept it.

Comment: MS Access can use single quotes if used consistently in expression. Likely the issue is spaces in column alias.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really use 3 different kinds of quotes: `”` and `'` and `’`? 
Use either `"` or `'`.
Also the alias `Date of Birth` should be enclosed in square brackets because it contains spaces, but since it exists already as a column in the table it will produce a *circular reference error* so change it to something like:

```
IIf(
  [Employee List].[Employee Type] = 'Employee',
  Format([Employee List].[Date of Birth], 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
  '01/01/1910'
) AS Date_of_Birth
```